# Parse Javascript objects to display hierarchical links directory

Tags: javascript, navigation, javascript-objects

i'm trying to make vanilla javascript parse a multi-nested object and then display the output. Its like a directory structure but for links, the user selects the top level box and then the next sub level box within inside of the top level box and so on.

[How the process works (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQI2j.png)

```
var p = {
"Item1":     
{
    "displayicon": "Item1-display",
    "url": "https://stackoverflow.com",
    "child":{
        "Item1.1":     
        {
            "displayicon": "Item1.1-display",
            "url": "https://www.google.com",
            "child": "value1"
        },
        "Item1.2": 
        {
            "displayicon": "Item1.2-display",
            "url": "https://www.w3schools.com",
            "child": { 
                    "Item1.2.1":     
                    { 
                    "display": "Item1.2.1-display",
                    "url": "http://www.google.com", 
                    }      
            }        
        }
    }
},
"Item2": 
{
    "displayicon": "Item2-display",
    "url": "https://stackoverflow.com",      
},
"Item3":
{
    "displayicon": "Item3-display",
    "url": "https://www.google.com",        
}
};


 //// this will navigate top level

for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + p[key].displayicon + " and " + p[key].url);
 }
}

 /// this navigate child levels ... 

 var xselected = 'Item1';

 for (var key in p[xselected].child) {
  if (p[xselected].child.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + p[xselected].child[key].displayicon + " and " + 
  p[xselected].child[key].url);
  }
 }
```

How can i make it navigate sub-sub child levels? The JSON can be any structure as long as it meets that process flow image. Im planning to use the 'displayicon' from the object to display an image and when you click on the image it takes you into child items of the section. But when you click on the url it takes you to the website. Also a back button to go up a level.

Ive searched the internet for vanilla javascript code but cant find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: JSONs are strings. You're talking about objects

Comment: I think I would do it another way: I should only have "Item" elements:
I don't know if you are able to do that, but I could be simpler because you don't have to deal with nested elements, just a reference to the item ID.

```"Item": [     
{
     "id": "e2gv"
    "displayicon": "Item1-display",
    "url": "https://stackoverflow.com",
    "childID": ['pqx8", "ap9qw" , ]
}, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make easy your work from this .

```
in PHP json_decode convert json data into PHP associated array
For Ex: $php-array= json_decode($json-data, true);
print_r($php-array);
```

Comment: Sorry not using php. It's a vanilla Javascript. How would you write an object for it work?

Comment: oh my bad . In js you can do like this 
JSON.parse(p)